# Given a complex function in $x$ and $y$ change into $z$, where $z=x+iy$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $$f(x,y)=\sinh{x}\sin{y}+e^y\sin{x}+i(e^y\cos{x}-\cosh{x}\cos{y}+C)$$ for $C$ a constant.

Now if I want to write this in terms of the complex variable $z$ I've heard that I can just set $x=z$ and $y=0$. Is this true? If so, this makes this terribly simple. We are given that the above equation is analytic.

Comment: Few weeks ago we've done it in our course of Complex analysis in the exact same way.

Answer (score 2):

$$g(z)=f(\Re(z),\Im(z))$$
If $z$ is real, then
$$g(z)=f(z,0)$$
Since $g$ and $z\rightarrow f(z,0)$ are both analytic and they're equal on the real line. Then they're equal on the complex plane.